# Accessing a Declared Variable

Tags: javascript, variables, document-ready, defined, fotorama

Good time. How do I access a declared variable? I declare like this:

```
$ (document) .ready (function () {

    var fotorama = $fotoramaDiv.data ('fotorama');

$ (document) .on ('click', '.btn-del-model', function (e) {

console.log (e);
console.log (fotorama); // Uncaught ReferenceError: fotorama is not defined

   });

});
```

The button with the ".btn-del-model" class is dynamically created. Tell me how to access the "fotorama" variable?

Comment: `$(fotoramaDiv).data ('fotorama')` did u tried this?

Comment: $(document).on('click', '.btn-del-model', function(e) {
       console.log($(fotoramaDiv).data('fotorama'));  //Uncaught ReferenceError: fotoramaDiv is not defined
    });

Comment: `fotoramaDiv` you need to get it from DOM. using class syntax or id. It would be better if you can share all your HTML code here

Comment: It worked! Thank you! Inattentively wrote the variable. 8)

Comment: I've added this info as an answer. You can mark the answer as accepted solution. Since it may help others as well.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to assign value in `fotoramaDiv` from DOM using class syntax or id.

```
// for example
const fotoramaDiv = document.querySelector('.yourClassName');
```